# MySQL: Extracting First Name or Last Name From Full Name Field

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, sql-like

In MySQL, I have a users table with a field called name. This name field can contain a full name or just first or last name. See example below. I am having a hard time writing a query where if I type in the first name it should return me a list of everyone with that first name or full name.

```
//MySQL query for finding user by name
findUserByName: (name) =>{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  pool.query(
    `SELECT id, user_image, name, email, is_online FROM users WHERE name = ?`,
    [name],
  (error, results, fields) =>{
    if(error){
      return reject(error);
    }
    else{
        return resolve(results);
    }
  }
);
})
},
```

```
//If I type mike it should return me all three of the below names. If I type mike jones it should only return me mike jones.
+------------+
|    name    |
+------------+
| Mike Jones |
+------------+
| Mike Brady |
+------------+
| Mike       |
+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't `like` do what you want?

```
SELECT id, user_image, name, email, is_online 
FROM users 
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
```

This searches for the parameter string anywhere in `name`. If you wanted to search at the beginning of the string only, you would change the predicate to:

```
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')
```